# Add count to specific elements in JList

Tags: java, swing, chat, jlist, messenger

I have a messenger project which shows all the on-line users in a `JList` and I want to show the count of unread messages in front of users having unread messages. I can do the code for getting unread messages and all but what I am not able to find a solution is to what I can do to show the user that he has unread messages and from which users. Any kind of solutions will be appreciated.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeUDv.png) is the frame I am working with.

Some information about the GUI, the  big text area on the right side is for showing messages received from selected user. And the text area below that is used for writing any text and send button is for sending that text to the selected user from the `JList`.

Comment: Create a `ListCellRenderer<User>` for the list. https://www.javaworld.com/article/2842240/learn-java/customizing-cell-rendering.html

Comment: *"Here is the frame I am working with."* I was about to embed that screen shot before I realized it provides no useful information. You've told us you have a list, but there is no information on what the other areas of the GUI do or why they're even on-screen (is one a text area intended to display the details of the user selected in the list?). The best advice we can offer based on that image (& problem description) has already been provided by @daniu.

Comment: Or maybe use a JTable. Then you can have multiple columns, 1 for the  count and the other for the user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please provide code example that you working on...

Comment: @sebast26 in code there is just a DefaultListModel that contains the elements that can be seen in the image (amit,ajay and all that) and the DefaultListModel is passes to JList. That's it nothing fancy.